# Cache API calls using AngularJS interceptor

Tags: angularjs, caching

Indent is to cache API calls by intercepting request and response using AngularJS interceptor. Below is my current code. I don't know what to do if the request exist in the cache. Is this feasible? Is this the right way to do it?

```
app.factory('apiCacheMiddleware', apiCacheMiddleware);

function apiCacheMiddleware($cacheFactory) {  
    var cache = $cacheFactory('apiCache');
    var interceptor = {
        request: function(config) {
            console.log(config)
            if(config.method === 'GET' && cache.get(config.url)){
                // What to return from here???
            }
            return config;
        },
        response: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if(response.config.method === 'GET'){
                cache.put(response.config.url, response.data);
            }
            return response;
        }
    };
    return interceptor;
};
```

Comment: I'm in the same stage as you are...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do (if you still happen to need it) is to assign the cache you created with `$cacheFactory` to the request (`config.cache = cache;` – it will probably be useful to check the previous value and take some decision upon it). On the response then, you will fill in that cache as you already do, and AngularJS will take care of the rest.